# An inner product on a space of linear maps

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ and $H$ be two complex Hilbert spaces. We suppose $V$ to be finite-dimensional. I'd like to understand the structure of Hilbert space on the space of linear mappings $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$.

Questions:

1. The space $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$ is a Banach space with respect to the operator norm. Does the norm give rise to an inner product?
2. Let $S$ be the unit sphere of $V$. Then we can define an inner product by embedding $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$ into $\mathrm{Map}(S,H)$. Namely for $f_1,f_2 \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$, we define $$(f_1,f_2):=\int_S(f_1(x),f_2(x))_Hdx.$$ Is the space $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$ complete with respect to the norm induced by the above inner product?

Notes:

1. To solve my first question, it is enough to see whether the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Parallelogram_identity_and_polarization) holds for the operator norm or not. But it is very difficult for me to check it.
2. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, the space $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$ admits the structure of a Hilbert space. Taking a basis of $V$, we can decompose $H$ into a direct sum $H^{\oplus \dim V}$. (The direct sum of (finite number of) Hilbert
   spaces is again a Hilbert space.) But I'd like to know whether $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$ can have the natural or geometric structure of a Hilbert space. (An inner product depending on the choice of the basis is unnatural.)
3. If $H$ is finite-dimensional, then $\mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$ has a natural inner product. Namely for $A,B \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,H)$, we define $(A,B):=\mathrm{tr}(A^*B).$ Here $A^*:H \to V$ is the dual of $A$.